# Running subreport ONLY on max of a group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix

I have a subreport in a tablix that I only want to run if the row has the maximum due date of a grouping.  The grouping I have is by part #.

Basically, if a row has the latest due date for that part #, I want the subreport to run/show.

I tried this for the hidden expression on the subreport, but it has some errors (too many arguments):

```
=IIF(Fields!DUE_DATE.Value = max(Fields!DUE_DATE.Value, "PART_NO"), "PurchasePart", False, True)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!DUE_DATE.Value = max(Fields!DUE_DATE.Value, "PART_NO"), False, True)
```

Note `IIF` function receives three arguments, you have an additional argument in your expression: `"PurchasePart"`.

```
=IIF(conditional,true branch,false branch)
```

Let me know if you need further help.